# Как сделать присвоение класса с отсчетом вложенности от текущего элемента?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать, чтобы исходя из данного скрипта класс `hidden` присваивался `div` с обратной вложенностью отсчитывая от класса `im-a-child` три уровня вложенности, т.е. для `im-a-parent`. Что-то подсказывает, что нужно использовать `lenght=`

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');

container.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const checkbox = e.target.closest('input[type="checkbox"]');

  if (!checkbox) return;

  const parentName = checkbox.getAttribute('data-parent');
  const state = checkbox.checked;

  toggleParent(parentName, state);
});

const toggleParent = (parentName, state) => {
  const parent = document.querySelector(`[data-parent-name=${parentName}]`);

  if (!parent)
    throw new Error(`Cannot found parent element with ${parentName} name.`);

  if (state) {
    parent.classList.add('hidden');
  } else {
    parent.classList.remove('hidden');
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox" class="hider-1" data-parent="first">
  <input type="checkbox" class="hider-2" data-parent="second">
</div>

<!--Хочу, чтобы меня скрыл hider1 -->
<div class="im-a-parent" data-parent-name="first">
  <div class="im-a-second-parent">
    <div class="im-a-child">Ребенок hider-1</div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--Хочу, чтобы меня скрыл hider2 -->
<div class="im-a-parent" data-parent-name="second">
  <div class="im-a-second-parent">
    <div class="im-a-child-2">Ребенок hider-2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если есть, возможность это все разместить в одном родителе, тогда можно так:

```css
.hider-1:checked~[data-parent-name="first"], .hider-2:checked~[data-parent-name="second"]{
   display: none
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox" class="hider-1" data-parent="first">
  <input type="checkbox" class="hider-2" data-parent="second">

<!--Хочу, чтобы меня скрыл hider1 -->
<div class="im-a-parent" data-parent-name="first">
  <div class="im-a-second-parent">
    <div class="im-a-child">Ребенок hider-1</div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--Хочу, чтобы меня скрыл hider2 -->
<div class="im-a-parent" data-parent-name="second">
  <div class="im-a-second-parent">
    <div class="im-a-child-2">Ребенок hider-2</div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Вариант с JS+jQuery:

```js
$('.fx-checkbox-hiders').on('change', '[data-parent]', function(){
    $('[data-parent]').each(function(){
       let selector =  $('[data-parent-name="'+$(this).attr('data-parent')+'"]');

       if(this.checked){
          selector.hide();
       }else{
          selector.show()
       }

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container fx-checkbox-hiders">
  <input type="checkbox" class="hider-1" data-parent="first">
  <input type="checkbox" class="hider-2" data-parent="second">
</div>

<!--Хочу, чтобы меня скрыл hider1 -->
<div class="im-a-parent" data-parent-name="first">
  <div class="im-a-second-parent">
    <div class="im-a-child">Ребенок hider-1</div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--Хочу, чтобы меня скрыл hider2 -->
<div class="im-a-parent" data-parent-name="second">
  <div class="im-a-second-parent">
    <div class="im-a-child-2">Ребенок hider-2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: К сожалению, они находятся в различных родителях

Comment: Подскажите. пожалуйста. вариант на JS

Comment: @flyflybird, добавил